# Get click count and impressions from lineitemid in Google Admanager (DFP)

Tags: google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I have a line item id stored in my DB, and i want using Admanager API to get click count, impressions number in PHP.

I saw on google groups that it was possible to do it using report generation and then parsing, but there is a faster way to do it (if possible i don't want to make a full report of my campaign)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reporting#building_a_reportquery) is an example of a Google Ad Manager query where you can get impressions and clicks for a particular order ID (which you can then change for [line item ID](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v201905/LineItemService.LineItem#id) in order to filter just for it). You can then [download the results](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reporting#downloading_the_report) of that query as a CSV file, and process them as you'd process any CSV file.